# Changed Archctaft Theme(OpenBox)

Tags: themes, openbox

I want change theme openbox but I don't know how.
I want to change it to this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tW2KQ.png)

I looked in OpenBox settings, but it only changes the manager style, and I want it to be just like on the screenshot.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming and is, as such, off-topic here; you may want to try asking over at [unix.se] or [su].